# What other Freemarker JSP Tag libraries are out-there?

Tags: libraries, jsp-tags, freemarker

I have been using Freemarker for a while and found [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) library very useful. I just wondering if there are any other libraries that could be used in similar means as [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/), which have been very helpful to you in development:

#### FTL page

```
<#assign display=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tlds/displaytag.tld"]/>
<@display.table uid="items" name="items" pagesize=10 class="table">
    <@display.column title="Category" property="category.name"/>
    <@display.column title="Delivery" property="delivery"/>
</@display.table>
```

Example of usage would be appreciated since most of the JSP tag libs don't have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro nest support, TemplateModel modify, Set param in a macro body, Template extend support, Access strut2 freemarker configuration in spring: http://code.google.com/p/freemarker-sweet/

Starter Web application template that integrates Maven, the Spring Framework, Hibernate + XDoclet, and Freemarker: http://mindoro.sourceforge.net/

General-purpose text file preprocessor tool: http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/

Cewolf: https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/freemarker-tags.html

Other JSP Tag libraries that could be integrated like above displaytag: http://java-source.net/open-source/jsp-tag-libraries